# How would one create a convolution filter in Swift for Tensorflow where only part of the matrix is trainable?

Tags: swift, tensorflow

Essentially I'm trying to make a convolution filter where only part of it is trainable, like this:

```
0T0
000
T0T
```

Where the 0 weights are set at zero and the T weights are trainable. I can set whole layers as trainable or not, but it's not clear at all how to set individual weights as trainable in a convolution layer.

[Edit]... OK, think I may have a workaround.

```
0T0                                1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4
000 applied stride 1,1 to an image 2,1 2,2 2,3 2,4 
T0T                                3,1 3,2 3,3 3,4
                                   4,1 4,2 4,3 4,4
```

is equivalent to:

```
                                                 3,1 1,2 3,3 3,2 1,3 3,4
TTT applied stride 1,3 to the transformed image: 4,1 2,2 4,3 4,2 2,3 4,4
```

In other words I can just transform the input tensor and then perform a normal convolution on the transformed input tensor...